Persist the Web3 Provider in Redux to use it across different parts of the application
Can anyone guide me on how to store a provider in Redux and make it persist, given that Redux doesn't allow storing non-serializable data. My use case involves using Web3Auth for Google login, which gives me a provider. I need to store that provider in Redux and use it across different pages of the web application.
